/proc/$pid/statm application reports on x86_64 (amd64) 4 times more mapped pages as same application on arm64 (aarch64)
We have a C++ multi-threaded application with shared libraries, running on linux x86_64 (debian-12, kernel 6.1.xx) and on a raspberry pi 5  ( arm64, debian-12, kernel 6.3.xx ). If I lock at /proc/$pid/statm.
/proc/$pid/statm reports 4 times the number of pages on x86_64 as on arm64 on the RPI5. The gcc- release generation command lines are identical with the exception of the -mtune option. The application creates the same number of threads with same stack-sizes on both architectures.
RPI5 arm64:
cat /proc/$(pgrep x4rtflex)/statm
150018 65643 7904 1 0 57587 0
Sum 1124.612061 MB

x85_64 ( core-i5-13500E )
cat /proc/$(pgrep x4rtflex)/statm
578665 245412 37759 1 0 207998 0
Sum 4279.340332 MB

I am exspecting that a 64-bit application will consume similar memory on both Architectures.

What is your question?

My question is: Why does the same application need 4 times more memory on an x86_64 than on arm64 ?

I withdraw the question!
I have found my mistake! I assumed that the raspberry pi 5 has the same pagesize as the raspberry pi 4, 4kB like a x86_64. The raspberry pi 5 uses a kernel MMU configuration with  16k pagesize.

ARMv8 allows a few different page size options, including 4 KB and, if I remember correctly, 64 KB.  You can select which one Linux uses by reconfiguring and recompiling your kernel.  Different distributions may have different defaults. Some programs might be hardcoded to assume 4 KB pages so they might break when it's 16 KB instead.  Also, some filesystems base their format on the native page size, so for instance, a btrfs filesystem created on your 16K-page system can't be mounted on a 4K-page system, or vice versa.
